# Working with file path strings on Linux, what encoding to use?

Tags: c++, linux, string, filepath

What encoding does Linux use for its file APIs? How should I work with path strings in C++, what class to use? I mean paths with non-ASCII characters. On Windows I use UTF-16 and `std::wstring`, on Mac - UTF-8 and my own UTF-8 string class. But unfortunately my class is not available on Linux, so what should I use?

Comment: I actually tend to avoid non ASCII or space characters in file paths.

Comment: @BasileStarynkevitch: I agree for programs, but it does not work well if your native language is not English. For example, I need to keep lots of video and music files which must have non-English names - otherwise they will completely lose their original meaning.

Comment: @BasileStarynkevitch: Me too, but I can't expect my german and japanese users to do the same :)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Internally, Linux permits to use any byte sequence for file name, except for null byte 0 and forward slash `'/'` (which is used as directory separator).

Common convention to permit Unicode file names on Linux is to use `UTF-8` encoding for file names. Easiest way to achieve that is to use good old `std::string` (not `std::wstring` which is suggested on Windows), however, you may need to write your own class which will validate that it is indeed valid `UTF-8`.

There are few examples of ready-to-use libraries that provide handling of `UTF-8` strings:

- [ICU](http://www.icu-project.org/) (robust but very heavy).
- [Glib::ustring](https://developer.gnome.org/libxml++-tutorial/stable/ch01s02.html) (has implicit casts to `std::string`, GPL).
- [UTF8-CPP](http://utfcpp.sourceforge.net/) (very lightweight, header-only).

Comment: Good answer, in pointing out that null bytes and slashes are special. +1

Comment: Thanks for the list of UTF-8 string libs, I will probably go with UTF8-CPP. So, when I call system APIs that return `char*`, I should expect UTF-8?

Comment: In general - yes, file names created by other programs should be encoded in `UTF-8`. You should expect that, but be ready to accept invalid `UTF-8`. This is like rule FCC 15 - play nice, but do not crash of others don't play nice.

Comment: Also, since there is no hard rule, maybe they were playing nice, once upon a time, with ISO-8559-1, or something.

Comment: Obligatory: note that you can static link ICU, configure it to be much smaller, etc, see docs.

Comment: if linux internally  permits any byte sequence for file\dir names what about paths? i mean '/' directory separator. Fs driver needs to know byte sequence for '/' however it depends of encoding generally speaking

Answer (score 1):

Linux does not enforce an encoding on file names. Using UTF-8 is common though.

Answer (score 0):

You can still use the standard type wchar_t (and %ls for printf/scanf when using wchar_t). This type allows you to use non-ascii characters.

```
wchar_t mystring[50] = L"sometext";
```

Note: that to make normal char string into wchar_t you have to use the pre-fix "L", you have to remember this is not the same as a char type so its a bit funny to use :o

Comment: This is not an answer to my question. I'm receiving strings from system calls as `char*`, and as far as I know there's no standard C++ way to convert UTF-8 to UTF-16.

Comment: sorry, I think I mis-understood your question.